# Differentiate between SomeType[] and SomeType[][] (1-dimensional vs 2-dimensional array type)

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

```
someFunction(someParameter: SomeType[] | SomeType[][]) {
// ...
}
```

In the function body how would I differentiate between the 2 possible array types of someParameter?

Comment: `Array.isArray(someParameter[0])` - If it's empty, then well, you choose how to interpret that.

Comment: maybe it is a better approach to have 2 distinct functions `work1d(arr: SomeType[])`, `work2d(arr: SomeType[][])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function isMatrix(value: any): value is any[][] {
    return Array.isArray(value[0]);
}

function someFunction(someParameter: SomeType[] | SomeType[][]) {
    if (isMatrix(someParameter)) {
        someParameter
//      ^? SomeType[][]
    } else {
        someParameter
//      ^? SomeType[]
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NngPBm)

---

If you want an empty array to be interpreted as a matrix, you can change the return in the type guard to this:

```
return !value.length || Array.isArray(value[0]);
```

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was looking for. 
Note: I changed `any` to `unknown` and typed `value` as [], so that ES-lint wouldn't complain.```function isMatrix(value: unknown[]): value is unknown[][] {
    return Array.isArray(value[0]);
}```